# How to capture a string starting with a specific string and stop after any space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to capture a specific word within a column. I want to extract the word that starts with 'lat'. Basically would like to capture latship , latprod, latdfu

| JobName |
| --- |
| pl_blob_consolidated - latship |
| pl_blob - latprod |
| pl_blob - latdfu - final |
| pl_blob - latdfu (final_blob) |
| pl_blob - latdfu - final_blob - sql |

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, JobName VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @tbl (JobName) VALUES
('pl_blob_consolidated - latship'),
('pl_blob - latprod'),
('pl_blob - latdfu - final'),
('pl_blob - latdfu (final_blob)'),
('pl_blob - latdfu - final_blob - sql');
```

Sample output:

| JobName |
| --- |
| latship |
| latprod |
| latdfu |
| latdfu |
| latdfu |

```
select DISTINCT   SUBSTRING(JobName, CHARINDEX('lat', JobName)
     , LEN(JobName) - CHARINDEX('lat', JobName) + 1) 
     , LEN(JobName) - CHARINDEX('lat', JobName) + 1 
 from tableName
```

Tried this, but won't stop after the word ends.

Thanks

Comment: What if there are two, e.g. `pl_blob - latprod - latship - final`? Or none?

Comment: no, there will always be one word with 'lat' in it. that is confirmed

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: can you show expected with text ?

Comment: find the position of lat, call it pos1, if found then find the position of space starting at pos1 + 1, if not found then pos2 = length of the string + 1, extract everything between those two positions. charindex accepts the 3rd argument - start position.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, JobName VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (JobName) VALUES
('pl_blob_consolidated - latship'),
('pl_blob - latprod'),
('pl_blob - latdfu - final'),
('pl_blob -> latdfu - final_blob'),
('pl_blob - latdfu - final_blob - sql');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , result = TRIM(value) 
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(JobName,'->','-'), '-')
WHERE TRIM(value) LIKE 'lat%';
```

**Output**

| id | JobName | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pl_blob_consolidated - latship | latship |
| 2 | pl_blob - latprod | latprod |
| 3 | pl_blob - latdfu - final | latdfu |
| 4 | pl_blob -> latdfu - final_blob | latdfu |
| 5 | pl_blob - latdfu - final_blob - sql | latdfu |

Comment: works well!
Quick question -> I see a 'value' column is generated as a result of the cross apply. What is this 'value' column exactly here?

Comment: It is a predefined column - output of `STRING_SPLIT()` function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: thanks. One last thing, I see you have split the data by '-' . What if it is not split by '-' ? I mean, what if one of the data is like ->    pl_blob - latdfu (final_blob )

Comment: That's why I asked to provide a minimal reproducible example. ##1-4

Comment: understood. let me know if you can help out with this, thanks

Comment: Please add that edge Test Case to the minimal reproducible example. #1 in your original question. And I will adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: I adjusted the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with some regular expressions (SQL Server function PATINDEX)
:
column name *myField*, table *myTable*:

```
SELECT 
/* index of first occurence of lat */
  SUBSTRING(myField, PATINDEX('%lat%', myField), 
/* up to index of first not char or digit or _  */
    PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9_]%',         
/* into the string after lat.  (+3 to be after t, up to the end) */
     SUBSTRING(myField, PATINDEX('%lat%', myField) + 3, LEN(myField))) - 1) 
 AS extracted_word
FROM myTable
WHERE myField LIKE '%lat%'
```